# Angular2 header unauthorized error

Tags: json, angular, angular2-http

I am new to angular. I am  doing some lab assignment for my course. The lab assignment is writing note taking application using angular 2.  I have been struggling with setting request header.  The user need to login to create a note.  When the user login to the application the node server send token as confirmation. I saved the token in localstorage. That works and i can see the token and print in component template . The post request must  append authorization to headers, i did append login credential. However i got 401 Unauthorized, when i send post request. Here my code
//response token is saved like this in local storage

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

    const body = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password}); // Stringify payload
    const headers = new Headers();

    headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/json' ); // ... Set content type to JSON
    const options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option

    return this._http.post(this.loginUser, body, options) // ...using post request
                     .map((res: Response) => {
                        const token = res.json() && res.json().token;
                        if (token) {
                            localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(res.json().id_token));
                            console.log(res.json().token);
                        }

                    })
                     .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}
```

//setting request head and send post request

```
createPost(title: string, text: string) {

  const body = JSON.stringify({noteData: {title: title, text: text}}); // Stringify payload
  const headers = new Headers();
  const token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
  headers.append( 'Content-Type', 'application/text' ); // ... Set content type to JSON
  headers.append('Authorization' , `Bearer ${token}`);
  const options    = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
    return this._http.post(this.createNote, body, options) // ...using post request
                     .map((res: Response) => {
                       console.log(res);
                    })
                     .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(
                       error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

}

Comment: The error you are getting is probably the response of your webserver which is caught in the .catch function. I would check your webserver

Comment: @DOMZE, i check web server catch, nothing is there